# TiledMap render uses 15% of my cpu

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick, lwjgl3

I am a beginner in Slick2D.
I used TiledMap render in my game,but I do not know why it  use 15%cpu and how to fix it.
I used map is 1024*768.
This is a part of my code.
Thanks for any help

```
 public class Map{
        public static Image[][] solids;
        public static int WIDTH;
        public static int HEIGHT;
        private static TiledMap map;
        private static int objectLayer;
        private static int mapEndX;
        private static int mapEndY;
        private static int  startX=0,realX=0;
        private static int  startY=0,realY=0;
        public static void render(){

            map.render(startX, startY);
        //  map.render(startX, startY, startX+60, startY+60, 80, 80);
        }

        public static void update(){


            map.getTileId(0, 0, objectLayer);
        } 

        public static void load(String name){

            map=Resources.getMap(name);
            objectLayer = map.getLayerIndex("solids");  
        } 

        public static void setStartXY(int tileX,int tileY){
            startX = (-1 * tileX * Tile.SMALL_SIZE);
            realX = ( -1 * startX);
            startY = (-1 * tileY * Tile.SMALL_SIZE);
            realY = ( -1 * startY);
            mapEndX = (startX + map.getWidth() * Tile.SMALL_SIZE);
            mapEndY = (startY + map.getWidth() * Tile.SMALL_SIZE);


        }

        public static boolean hitTest(int x,int y){

        /*  if((map.getTileId((x+startX)/4-1, (y+startY)/4-1,objectLayer) ==0)){            
                return true;
            }*/
            return false;
        }

    }
```

//----------------------------------------------

```
 public class  Play extends BasicGameState{
         int x=0,i=100,j=50;
         int y=0;
         private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
         private TiledMap map;  
         Image image;
        public Play(int play) {

        }

        @Override
        public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame arg1) throws SlickException {
            try {
                    Map.load("test");
                    Map.setStartXY(0, 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
            entities.add(new Player());
            System.out.println("1");

        }

        @Override
        public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame arg1, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

            g.setBackground(Color.black);
        //  g.scale(4f, 4f);
            Map.render();

            for(int i=0;i < entities.size();i++){

                entities.get(i).render(gc, g);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbd, int delta) throws SlickException {
            for(int i=0;i < entities.size();i++)
            {
                try {
                    entities.get(i).update(gc, delta);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Map.update();

        }

        @Override
        public int getID() {

            return state.Play;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Did you use a profiler to measure the execution? If so, you should be able to drill down to find where the time is going. Also, what are you using for comparison that makes you think 15% is too much?

Answer (score -2):

The reason why your game takes up 15% CPU is because of your map size, which is 1024*768, and the game constantly has to run this map several times each second in the render() method, which of course would take up memory. I would suggest following this tutorial on TiledMap rendering (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BivL6Carh4), start watching at around 6 minutes into the video, this individual will teach you how to render the map efficiently and this will of course take up less memory for your game. Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont believe this to be the case, because you can create complex 3d Survival games on a huge map that takes up less cpu than that. So i believe it to be something else.